Python : Speed up FFT over an axis in an multidimensional data
I would like to know if there is a better way to speed up the performance of my FFT over the first dimension of a tensor that is 1000 x 512 x 512, for example
I tried the following to overcome memory issues
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
z = torch.randn(1000,512,512)
for ii in tqdm(range(z.shape[-1]), total = z.shape[-1], desc='Applyinf FFT 1D'):
    for jj in range(z.shape[1]):
        z[...,jj, ii] = torch.fft.fftshift(torch.fft.fft(z[...,jj,ii].to(device), dim = 0), dim = 0).abs().cpu()

But it seems that the only thin for me to do is to batch in the last dimensions until I find an optimal compromise between time and memory usage for my fft

Your loop certainly results in many CPU/GPU synchronization and I expect the work not to be enough to saturate GPU SIMD units, so bad performance. You should use multiple streams to avoid this and preallocated pinned memory used as a temporary buffer between the CPU and GPU. IDK how to do this with torch. If the memory of your GPU is so limited, maybe a parallel CPU implementation is better. You can try the FFTW for that (just be aware that the FFT plan should be done only once before the computation).

Try to transpose your array first and apply fft on last dimension instead of first. It probably will be faster (more CPU-cache friendly).
